# ChartJs Force scatter plot to be square shaped

Tags: javascript, plot, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I am trying to create a scatter plot where XAxes and YAxes is the same scale and size. 
The plot will become a square with identical Axes.
Therefore if the data be {x:0, y:0}, {x:100, y:100}
it draws a diagonal (45 degrees) line. I am plotting  A vs. B and the rectangular shape of the plot is confusing.

The max values are known ahead of time.

Answer (score 5):

in dataset you can set the pointStyle.

```
      datasets: [{pointStyle:'rect'}]
```

for the other [types](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/elements#point-styles)

Answer (score 2):

Just found it : 
just add aspectRatio: 1 to options